# How to remove submodule reference from pull request?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I accidentally added a submodule reference to git commit and then I pushed it.
So in my branch in repo I have now file "__submodule-name" with reference included. How can I remove this file from repo?

Answer (score 1):

A submodule reference, in a commit, is a "file" of type *gitlink*.

To remove the reference, you must fix the commit.  Unfortunately it is impossible to change any commit, once it is made.  So you can't fix it.  The best (and only) thing you can do instead is to make a *new and improved* commit, that you use *instead of* the bad commit, where the new and improved commit is otherwise the same as the original, but has removed the bad "file" (the gitlink).

One removes a gitlink with the same command one uses to remove a file: `git rm --cached`.  One *creates* (adds) a gitlink with the same command one uses to create a file, after all: it's `git add` that created the gitlink.  So `git rm` is the way to remove it.  There's a little bit of asymmetry here though because:

- `git add` *adds* a gitlink when you try to add a directory-that-contains-a-Git-repository.  Because you cannot put a Git repository inside a commit (Git won't let you do that), `git add` puts in the gitlink instead.

  Note that the sub-directory that contains the sub-module (the inner Git repository) is a whole folder full of files.  These files exist in your *working tree*.  The `git add` step writes a single file, of type `gitlink`, into Git's *index*, which Git also calls the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*.
- `git rm` normally tries to remove both the file in your working tree—that's the one you can see and work with—and the index.  But what you have in your working tree isn't just a file, or just a gitlink: it's a whole directory (folder) full of files, containing a whole nother Git repository.  A simple `git rm` can't remove that, and you might not want it to try.

  Hence you want `git rm --cached`.  Here's that word *cache* showing up: that extra third name for Git's staging area or index.  This tells `git rm` that it should only remove the file (or gitlink) from the staging area, and not try to remove anything from your working tree.

There's one remaining problem, which is the same rather large problem everyone always has the first time they do something like this.  If the commit that needs repair is not the *most recent* commit—or if more than one commit needs repairing—it's just *hard to do*.  This sort of thing is why people write big fancy programs like The BFG, or `git filter-repo`, or the like.

**If you only need to fix (replace with new-and-improved) the *last, most-recent* commit**, a simple `git rm --cached <submodule>` and `git commit --amend` will usually do the trick.  Make sure you did not add the submodule as a full-blown submodule using `git submodule add` earlier, though.  (Most people who are having this problem did not, and for some reason completely ignored the very long message that `git add` spewed out at them earlier when they ran the `git add` that created the problem.  Apparently people think Git spews output at them just to confuse them—probably because sometimes, Git *does* seem to do this!  Git is not very user-friendly, sometimes.)

Since you *pushed* the "bad" commit, you'll need to use `git push --force-with-lease` or similar to push the new-and-improved replacement commit.  See any of the *very, very many* StackOverflow questions about this.